# 'Image' object has no attribute '_committed'

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I am trying to resize my picture into 124*124 size. I searched alot and find some solutions for related problem. But My problem is not solved even though.

My model

```
class MyUsers(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='user')
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='static/photo', blank=True)
    name = models.CharFiled(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My view

```
def change_user_photo(request, id):
    if request.method == "POST":
        new_pic = request.FILES['new']
        if new_image:
            my_user = MyUser.objects.get(id=id)
            image = Image.open(new_pic)
            image = image.resize((124,124), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            my_user.image = image
            my_user.save()
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('my_profile'))        
    else:
        user = get_photo(id)
        return render(request, "photo/edit.html", 
          {"users":user})
```

My Template:

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpload">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>New Photo:</label>
         <input type="file" name="new"/>
     </div>
     <hr/>
     <div class="form-group">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn- 
            success">Update</button>
     </div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 8):

image = models.FileField() only takes Fileupload object and you are passing image object .

```
def image_resize(self, field):

    if field:
        image = Img.open(field)
        image = image.convert('RGB')
        image = image.resize((800, 800), Img.ANTIALIAS)
        output = io.BytesIO()
        image.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=85)
        output.seek(0)
        return InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField',
                                    field.name,
                                    'image/jpeg',
                                    sys.getsizeof(output), None)
    else:
        return None
```

InMemoryUploadedFile available in django.core.files.uploadedfile . convert the image in fileupload object

Comment: Getting the same error when using the DFR with Base64Image()